# How do I hide a property from the WPF window XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

As far as I can see all my custom control properties are editable directly from WPF window XAML. Is there any way to hide some of them? We have properties that have absolutely no meaning to be set when the application starts and need to be changed later at runtime.

The only idea that comes in my mind is to change them to methods? What do you think?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to annotate the members with `[BrowsableAttribute(false)]`?

Comment: Yes, this hides them from the Visual Studio object properties but you can still recall them in XAML and set them.

Comment: how do you 'recall' them? and what control are you using for editing the properties?

Comment: I mean while you are writing XAML for your custom control, you can access any property and change them.

Comment: If the property is public why can't it be edited/exposed?

Comment: We have some properties specific to our business that have absolutely no meaning in the design-environment (XAML)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `EditorBrowsableAttribute` to hide a property from the XAML editor. Setting this attribute to `EditorBrowsableState.Never`on a property will hide it.

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public int BusinessProperty {get; set;}
```

More info here: [EditorBrowsableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 class Name {
   public int x;
 }
```

x will be a field, not a property.

Comment: What if you need to add some logic after changing `x`?

Comment: It doesn't sound reasonable to me to change properties to fields just for suppressing IntelliSense in the XAML designer. There are good reasons to use properties rather than fields.

Comment: This is a solution. Ok, it has obvious drawbacks. But it's a solution anyway, isn't it ? )